# Append child to referenced div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a list of ID's which I go through and then i want to append a newly created iFrame to each one.

```
$.each(elm, function(key, value) {
  var id = (data[key].id).split(':')[2];
  var iframe = $('<iframe>', { src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id +
    '?controls=' + settings.controls +
    '&rel=' + settings.rel +
    '&showinfo=' + settings.showinfo,

    frameborder: settings.frameborder,
    width: settings.size[0],
    height: settings.size[1],
    allowfullscreen: settings.allowfullscreen
  });
  $(value).appendChild(iframe);
  $(value).find('.youtube_title').html(data[key].title);
  $(value).find('.youtube_link').attr({ target: '_blank', src: data[key].link['@attributes'].href });
  $(value).find('.youtube_channel').html(data[key].author.uri);
});
```

However im getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e(...).appendChild is not a function(…)

If I do `$(value).html(iframe);` this works fine!

Comment: The jQuery function is [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: @JasonP thanks! Add that as an answer?

Comment: close it as typo ? now has no value for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `.append()`.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

`appendChild()` is a DOM method, not a jQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

append is a jQuery method to append some content or HTML to an element.

```
$(value).append('Some text or HTML');
```

appendChild is a pure DOM method for adding a child element.

```
document.getElementById('example').appendChild(newElement);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtb51wed/

Is there a way to convert jquery object selector method to html dom objects

```
$(value)[0].appendChild(newElement);
```